# Azure Blob storage batch update. Possible?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to update blobs metadata in an existing container. I currently have more than 5k blobs in one container. What I do as of now:

- blobs are received via `container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync()` with `BlobContinuationToken`
- then I'm aggregating the tasks from `blob.UpdateMetadataAsync()` and run them concurrently via `Task.WhenAll()`

All in all, it takes around 10 seconds on my machine for the whole process. But as I understand, I'm creating a pressure on the network as I need to send 5k requests to the Azure and it needs to process all of them.

Is there a better way? Can I send a batch request to do the task or I'm left with the current approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I send a batch request to do the task or I'm left with the current approach?

I don't think that there is a way to send a batch request to do that.

From the [Azure storage blob Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api), you could know that there is no such Rest API.

But if you have any ideas about Azure storage, you could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure team.

Sure. you could use the async and concurrently way to update the blobs.

> Is there a better way?

If you don't want to send the such much requests from client.

I recommand that you could do that with [Azure function http trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook). And implement the updating blobs logic in the Azure function.

For more information about Azure function, please refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need to pre-populate my blobs metadata exactly for Functions logic I already have.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch API for Blob Storage is [now in preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/batchapiforblob/). Unfortunately for now, it only support DeleteBlob and SetBlobTier operations but support for more operations is coming.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch